# i can't load picture with "LoadImage" and draw it in dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

```
void CCreateList::paintRowList(CDialogEx* CCurent, int wBeginX, int wBeginY)
{
    CPaintDC dc(CCurent);
    CDC *cdc,cc;
    cdc=CCurent->GetDC();
    HANDLE hbitmap;
    hbitmap = LoadImage(0,L"C:\\PIC.png",IMAGE_BITMAP,100,100,0x00000010);
    cc.CreateCompatibleDC(cdc);
    cc.SelectObject(hbitmap);
    dc.BitBlt(100,100,100,100,&cc,0,0,SRCCOPY);
}
```

i want draw a title with a image in dialog. Don't use Picture Control please help me.

Comment: Okay, well loading an image and displaying it are 2 separate and distinct operations. Which one are you having trouble with? (It looks like it's the loading.) Have you tried the same with a .BMP image? You need to use GDI+ to load a png...

Answer (score 5):

Here's the code I use for loading other image formats. It relies on GDI+, so you need to initialize & shutdown, before and after it's been used (once per program is enough)

**Load Routine:**

```
// BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF, Exif, WMF, and EMF
HBITMAP mLoadImg(WCHAR *szFilename)
{
   HBITMAP result=NULL;

   Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(szFilename,false);
   bitmap->GetHBITMAP(NULL, &result);
   delete bitmap;
   return result;
}
```

**Init/shutdown**

```
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
   static Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
   static ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;

    // so we can load all the image formats that windows supports natively - (I'm using a transparent PNG on the main dialog)
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    // make things look pretty
    InitCommonControls();

    // run the app
    //DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DialogProc);
    //
    // 
    //

    // clean-up stuff
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

    return 0;
}
```

Naturally, this is for a dialog-based app (dialog is defined in resource.rc) - rather than a frame-based one, or an MFC one. The point is, you just need to initialize before you use it, and shutdown afterwards.

Comment: thanks ... more a question ... can i add a dialog on a dialog? Can you help me ???

Comment: Add a dialog on a dialog?? Er, no. That does not make sense. Just like you can't add a button to a button. What are you trying to achieve? There is a better/proper way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

i were do it with :

```
CString strFileName;
        strFileName="C:\\PIC.bmp";
        BITMAP bmpPro;
        HBITMAP bmpHandle=(HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,strFileName,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0, LR_LOADFROMFILE| LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);

        CBitmap bmpPicture;
        CDC mdcPicture;
        bmpPicture.Attach(bmpHandle);
        bmpPicture.GetBitmap(&bmpPro);
        mdcPicture.CreateCompatibleDC( &dc);
        CBitmap * bmpPrevious = 
                mdcPicture.SelectObject(&bmpPicture);
                dc.BitBlt(wCurrent, wBeginY,
        header[i].getWidthOfHeader(), wHeight,
                    &mdcPicture, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

and i were successful :X
thanks:X

Comment: You're welcome. Thought that was the problem. don't use MFC, so wasn't certain at first that the LoadImage function was just the one found in  WinUser.h. See added answer for a routine to load png, wmf, tif, etc.